# Unable to reset all the choices in SelectInput

Tags: react-admin

The user needs to select a project in the AutocompleteInput first, doing that will set the filter property on the ReferenceInput which will load the possible values from the server into the SelectInput choices list. The data is fetched from the server however, if the choice that was selected in the SelectInput is no longer in the list, it is not reset. Furthermore the selected value is still in the choices list even though it was not returned from the rest service.
This is the code i wrote that has this issue:

```
<ReferenceInput label="Project" source="projectId" reference="projecten" filterToQuery={searchText => ({ naam: searchText })}>
    <AutocompleteInput optionText="naam" optionValue="id" inputValueMatcher={() => null} />
</ReferenceInput>
<FormDataConsumer>
    {({ formData, ...rest }) => {
        return  <ReferenceInput label="Lot" source="lotId" reference="loten" filter={{ projectId: formData.projectId }} {...rest}>
                    <SelectInput optionText="lotNummer"/>
                </ReferenceInput>
    }}
</FormDataConsumer>
```

How do I reset the SelectInput onChange of the AutocompleteInput and not load the currently selected value?

Comment: Hi @TomJ , I'm facing the same problem , if you found a way , please share the solutions.

Comment: Hi @MohamedNizar, Apparently it is seen as a feature. I think the issue is in the reducer. However I convinced my client just to select a new item every time the autocomplete is changed. To be honest, i hate this solution but for now it will have to do. If you find a solution, please let me know. If you use the choices property, it will reset but then you can not use the referenceinput.

Comment: Yep, I  have moved to choices as much possible to avoid the reference input.But my case I have many time to use RefernceInput .I'll work around it and share here if I had time.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a late reply, but it might help someone. I achieved the same effect by using following steps on two `SelectInput`s inside a `ReferenceInput` each. I hope it works for your structure as well.

1. import `change` from `redux-form`

   `import { change } from redux-form`
2. Give your `SimpleForm` a name

   `<SimpleForm form="myForm"...`
3. Move your first `ReferenceInput` inside the `FormDataConsumer`

   `<FormDataConsumer>
       {({ formData, ...rest }) => {
           return (
               <div>
                   <ReferenceInput label="Project" ...
                   <ReferenceInput label="Lot" ...
               </div>
           );
       }
   </FormDataConsumer>`
4. Add an `onChange` to your first `ReferenceInput`

   `<ReferenceInput 
       label="Project" source="projectId" reference="projecten"
       filterToQuery={searchText => ({ naam: searchText })}
       onChange={() => {rest.dispatch(change('myForm', 'lotId', ''))}} >`
5. Add a `key` property to your second `ReferenceInput` and use your first `ReferenceInput`'s source as it's value

   `<ReferenceInput label="Lot" source="lotId"
       reference="loten" filter={{ projectId: formData.projectId }} 
       key={formData.projectId} {...rest}>`

Finally you'll get

```
<SimpleForm name="myForm">
    <FormDataConsumer>
        {({ formData, ...rest }) => {
            return  (
                <div>
                    <ReferenceInput label="Project" source="projectId"
                        reference="projecten"
                        filterToQuery={searchText => ({ naam: searchText })}
                        onChange={() => {rest.dispatch(change('myForm', 'lotId', ''))}} >
                        <AutocompleteInput optionText="naam" optionValue="id"
                            inputValueMatcher={() => null} />
                    </ReferenceInput>
                    <ReferenceInput label="Lot" source="lotId" reference="loten"
                        filter={{ projectId: formData.projectId }}
                        key={formData.projectId} {...rest} >
                        <SelectInput optionText="lotNummer" />
                    </ReferenceInput>
                </div>
            );
        }}
    </FormDataConsumer>
</SimpleForm>
```

I used the steps from [this link](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/2431#issuecomment-453071677) and added the `key` property according to another SO question but I'm unable to find it now.

Comment: Hi, I have used your solution...but I have this error.... "TypeError: rest.dispatch is not a function"... what is happen? Regards